# Printing a , in CSV file using c programming

Tags: c, csv, printf

```
FILE * fp = fopen ("excel.csv" , " w+ ");
fprintf (fp, "%s", "hello,world");
```

I want to print `hello,world` with comma in a single cell.
How can I print the same without printing in two different cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around the cell:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", "\"hello,world\"");
```

IIRC Wikipedia has [a pretty good article on CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules).

Comment: Actually, adding the quotes to the second argument is better, as that allows to quote a variable char array, unlike the string literal: fprintf(fp, "\"%s\"", "hello, world");

Comment: Unless you have something in the string you also need to escape, like a quotation mark, or if the writer is in a common path for strings and numeric values and all you're doing is writing. Basically, the case you cite (a variable string) is actually the case where you usually won't want to put the quotes in the format string.